# How to make the page fits in A3 or A4 for printing in libreoffice/openoffice draw

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice, drawing

I've a problem to print a file LibreOffice draw, the draw doesn't fit in the page printed.

When created the draw, I adjusted the size so that format of the page is not A4 or A3.

Anyone has any Idea how could I print the whole draw to fit in one page?

I'm using LibreOffice draw on Ubuntu.

Comment: As you discovered, the document is formatted based on the page size selected.  A few options: 1) change the page size setting, then manually adjust the content as needed to fit. 2) See if you have a "fit to paper size" setting in the printer preferences.  3) Output to a PDF (or use a PDF printer driver).  PDF readers typically have an option to fit to paper size (if the paper size is smaller).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for the 2nd and 3rd option I've tried but it doesn't work properly, when I export to pdf and I try to print the printer refuses, when I try fit to paper, it cuts the bottom and the right part of the draw, so may be the 1st option will work, but I don't know how to adjust the contents to fir into the page size..do you know exacly how could this be done with libreoffice draw?

Comment: By futzing with it by hand, adjusting sizes of each object and whatever else needs adjusting (did I neglect to mention that this option is a total pain in the butt?).  One other thought: see if there's an option to output pages as an image.  Most image viewers will fit to page when you print, or you can resize the images.  For that matter, you can convert the PDF's to an image using online utilities, like https://smallpdf.com/.

Comment: I've installed pdfposter so that I can convert pdf to another pdf file, more adapted for printing, the problem now is that the font size is very small...may be if I have time I'll re-create the draw from scratch.Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by using [pdfposter](https://gitlab.com/pdftools/pdfposter) (which may be available in your distro's repository):

```
pdfposter input_file.pdf output_file.pdf -m a3
```